# How can I add custom text in a row above an attribute in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I was using this function to add text next to the attribute label, however I need it above or below an attribute, for example something like "Please choose desired colour" right above (or below) the pa_colour attribute.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3 );
function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$name;

    if( $taxonomy == 'pa_size' )
        $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';

    return $label;
}
```

The problem is, I'm not sure how to do that. If you can direct me I would greatly appreciate it.

What I'd like to see:
[image]

What I'm seeing now:
[image]

Comment: `$label = '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT', 'woocommerce') . '</div>' . $label;`

Comment: @Reigel i think you have to post this as answer instead of comment.

Comment: Hint: here you can see how many ways `wc_attribute_label` function can be used => [LINK](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wc_attribute_label&type=). So be careful about what kind of content you are adding and where.

Comment: @Reigel Unfortunately that's just pushing out the variation swatches to the far right instead of being on the top: https://snag.gy/QfAux5.jpg. What i'm hoping to see is something like this: https://snag.gy/L10cCp.jpg

Comment: add `.custom-label { display: block; }` to your style.css

Comment: also, add `is_product`, so it will work only on product page... `if( is_product() && $taxonomy == 'pa_size' )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no hook that can easily get what you want. Because the html looks like this:

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
                <td class="value">
                    <?php
                        $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( stripslashes( urldecode( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ) ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                        wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
                        echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) : '';
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

you are using the filter for `wc_attribute_label` which is called inside a `<td>` tag.
What you want to achieve needs to be in its own `tr` `td` at least.

What I can suggest is for you to continue with what you have and then get what you want to achieve by either using `css` or `jQuery`.

Better yet copy `woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` to `yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` and do your edits on that file.

Comment: If I were to create a child-theme and modify the table you mentioned, where can I find this template in woocommerce?

Comment: copy `woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` to `yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`

Comment: PERFECT. Found it, added the tr/td above the loop, it's good now! https://snag.gy/P9Ztrf.jpg